How to solve the transient response of a general $RLC$ network?
There is a $RLC$ network $\{V_i\}$ with a complex impedance $Z_{ij}$ on each edge. all vertices have initial voltage $V_i$ and all edges have initial current $I_{ij}$. Now, is there a general way to solve the later dynamics of the system? That is, to solve for $i_{ij}(t)$ and $v_i(t)$.
I know the method when we have a AC source and we can make the current complex and treat the impedance just like resistors. However, I don't know how to apply this method on the transient process.

Laplace transformation is the usual way of doing this.

In circuits consisting of actual RLC elements, you will have many redundant initial conditions which must be self-consistent, otherwise the problem will be ill-defined. You only need the initial capacitor voltages and inductor currents. These would then appear as current and voltage sources in the circuit in Laplace domain. If your circuit consists of arbitrary impedances (non-RLC), you need to know the values of the impedances for all values of $\omega$ (or $s$) to be able to translate them to time domain. This would a complicated problem and I don't know if there is a general approach.

As a general comment: the standard way to deal with such transients is via Laplace transforms.

The standard way of doing it is to convert the initial conditions to equivalent sources. The idea is all based on a well known property of the Laplace transform, see the table in here.
If $$f(t)  \leftrightharpoons F(p)$$ then
$$\frac{df(t)}{dt}  \leftrightharpoons pF(p)-f(0)$$
This means, in the context of an inductor for which $$v_L(t)=L\frac{di}{dt},$$ the Laplace transform of its induced voltage is
$$V_L(p)=pLI(p) - Li(0) \tag{1}.$$
Since the the Laplace transform of $\delta (t)$ is just $1$, when writing $$V_L(p)+ Li(0)=pLI(p) \tag{2}$$ the term $Li(0)$ in Eq (1) can be viewed as the Laplace transform of a voltage source $v_{oL}(t)=Li(0)\delta(t)$ in series with the inductor itself whose impedance is, of course, $pL$.
Similarly, you have the capacitor equation :
$$i_c(t)=C\frac{dv_c(t)}{dt}$$ whose Laplace transform is
$$I_c(p)=CpV_c(p)-Cv_c(0) \tag{3},$$ which we will write as
$$V_c(p)=\frac{1}{pC}I_c(p)+\frac{v_c(0)}{p} \tag{4}.$$
Since $\frac{1}{p}$ is the Laplace transform of the unit step function $1(t)$ that is defined as  $$1(t)=0 \text{  for  } t<0\\ 1(t)=1 \text{  for  } t>0,$$ the term $\frac{v_c(0)}{p}$ in Eq 4 represents a constant voltage source, a battery, $v_{oC}(t)=v_c(0)1(t)$ in series with the capacitor whose impedance is $\frac{1}{pC}$, and the battery is to be switched on at $t=0.$

For the successful application of the initial conditions @Puk's comment is very important. The two Kirchhoff's laws, KVL and KCL, are differential equations and as such must include consistent initial conditions and connection rules. For example, one may not connect two ideal voltage sources in parallel of different voltages or connect two ideal current sources of different currents in series because the resulting voltage drop or branch current cannot have two different values simultaneously.
Similar indeterminacy results when two capacitors are connected in parallel or two inductors are connected in series. For capacitors the initial voltages and for inductors the initial must be consistent.
A simple way to assure such and similar consistency requirement is to represent every connecting lead/wire with a arbitrarily small but finite resistance. In practice, this would amount to adding a small resistance to every branch in the circuit. Now when you also follow the prescription I described above, that is representing every initial inductor current or initial capacitor voltage with an ideal voltage source, an impulse for the inductor or a step for a capacitor,  then the consistency of the initial conditions will be assured by that positive branch resistance.
Of course, there is nothing special about ideal voltage sources in series. You can achieve all I described above by converting every initial condition into a parallel coupled current source, an impulse current for the capacitor and a step current for the inductor, and have an arbitrarily large but finite resistor connect the endpoints to ensure consistency of the prescribed currents. Wile it is a matter of taste which is to be preferred, the voltage sources in series lying on the same branch is probably simpler for direct impedance calculations.
